# Nothing in my sql database table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

This is my first asp.net web application that needs a sql database. I configured the database with the table and all of the columns that I need on my webserver.

What i did so far is in web.config:

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=; Initial Catalog=; User ID=; Password=;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

and in a simple application form:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource nexusdb = new SqlDataSource();
    nexusdb.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ToString();

    nexusdb.InsertCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
    nexusdb.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO Windows (Firstname, Lastname, Email, Phone, Company, Date, IPAddress) VALUES (@Firstname, @Lastname, @Email, @Phone, @Company, @Date, @IPAdress)";

    nexusdb.InsertParameters.Add("Firstname", FirstNametxtbox.Text);
    nexusdb.InsertParameters.Add("Lastname", LastNametxtbox.Text);
    nexusdb.InsertParameters.Add("Email", Emailtxtbox.Text);
    nexusdb.InsertParameters.Add("Phone", Phonetxtbox.Text);
    nexusdb.InsertParameters.Add("Company", Companytxtbox.Text);
    nexusdb.InsertParameters.Add("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    nexusdb.InsertParameters.Add("IPAddress", Request.UserHostAddress.ToString());
}
```

However nothing in my table ?!

Comment: Where are you executing the command?

Comment: in a submit button : <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="contact_us.aspx.cs" Inherits="contact_us" %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this article about [Inserting Data Into a SQL Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720188%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). You will find it in both `C#` and `VB`
 This got good example of inserting data in to database

Answer (score 3):

You never executed the command.

Since you just want to execute a command, you should use a `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` directly, and call `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connection string))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT ... ", connection)) {
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", someValue);
    connection.Open();

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're actually executing the command.  Try creating a SqlCommand with that insert statement, fill the parameters as you're doing now, and then execute the command.

Comment: could you please give me an example